# Why my code is only incrementing this value 1 time in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function increase1() {
  var a = document.getElementById('increase').value;
  ++a
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = a
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Counter app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="counter" value="0">0</p>
  <br>
  <button id="increase" onclick="increase1()">increase</button><br><br>
  <button id="decrease">decrease</button>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

This is the code I have pre incremented please check, and please check what should I change in this code man please

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementById('increase').value;
```

don't get the new value change it by

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the value of the counter and increment/decrement then update the value of the counter.
Please find the updated code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Counter app</title>
    <script>
      function increase1() {
        let counterElement = document.getElementById("counter");
        let count = parseInt(counterElement.value);
        counterElement.value = ++count;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="counter" type="number" value="0" />
    <br />
    <button id="increase" onclick="increase1()">increase</button><br /><br />
    <button id="decrease">decrease</button>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Similarly, you can write the function for decrementing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting value from button which is an issue

```
var a = document.getElementById('increase').value;
```

You should get current counter value like this.

```
var a = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
```

See below run able code for increment and decrement of counter value.

```js
function increase1() {
  var a = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML =  ++a;
}
function decrease1() {
  var a = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = --a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Counter app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="counter" value="0">0</p>
  <br>
  <button id="increase" onclick="increase1()">increase</button><br><br>
  <button id="decrease" onclick="decrease1()">decrease</button>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```